# AWS athena hive remove footer from csv file

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, csv, hive

While creating table in AWS Athena i have a problem with removing footer from imported csv file stored in AWS S3.

The query is pretty simple but im stuck on footer part.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE csvfile
(
  col1 string
  col2 string
  col3 string
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION
's3://xxxxx'
TBLPROPERTIES ("skip.header.line.count"='1',"skip.footer.line.count"='1');
```

The header is working perfectly fine but footer is not ;/ Any idea how to do it?

The problem is that "skip.footer.line.count"='1' is not removing the last row (summary in the csv file)

Comment: What is not working? What is the expected vs actual output?

Comment: "skip.footer.line.count"='1' is not removing the last line in csv